# どうしたの or どうしたのか？

Tags: grammar

In [どうしたの？] the の is seeking explanation right?

What's the diffence between [どうしたの？] and [どうしたのか？] ?

both are casual speaking but is the first one more feminine?

I know the formal one would be [どうしたのですか？]

Thank you :)

Comment: [どうしたんですか] is more natural.

Comment: I hear a lot in animes ［どうしていたの？] , but I have lately noticed it more on the female characters so I am not sure if adding か, in the end will turn it more male oriented in casual speech. I've heard that in affirmation like [行きたいの！] gives the idea of immaturity and mainly of girly talk if you do not put だ or です at the end.

Comment: Yes, どうしたの is feminine word.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki Are you from western Japan, if not a foreigner?

Comment: @user4092 My both parents are from tokyo.  I live in kanagawa  where is neiborhood of  tokyo.

Comment: I'm sorry. I believed it was rare for people around there to sense that it's particularly a feminine expression. I've just learned something new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

どうしたの？ is often considered feminine, but many guys use it, too (though it might depend on the region).

You don't really say どうしたのか？ to mean "What's wrong?" in conversation.*
You'd rather say どうしたんだ？ or just どうした？ to sound masculine.

You'd use ～のか？ in yes-no questions, as in:

> - どうしたんだ？お[腹]{なか}が[痛]{いた}い**のか**？
>     What's wrong? Do you have a stomachache?
> - [何]{なに}してるんだ？[勉強]{べんきょう}してる**のか**？
>     What are you doing? Are you studying?
> - どこに[行]{い}ってたんだ？[学校]{がっこう}には行った**のか**？
>     Where have you been? Did you go to school?

<sub>The examples above would sound pretty masculine. To sound feminine, you could say like 「どうしたの？お腹が痛いの？」「何してるの？勉強してるの？」「どこに行ってたの？学校には行ったの？」</sub>

And yes, its polite/formal version is どうしたのですか？
In speech, it's usually pronounced どうした**ん**ですか？

<sub>*You might see 「何/どう/どこ etc + のか？/のだろうか？のであろうか？etc」 in formal but not polite writing. You'd also see 「何/どう/どこ etc + か」 in subordinate clauses, eg 「何をしている**のか**、わからない。」</sub>

Comment: ohh thank you, clears it up everything! i didn't know you could use だ in a question, but since it is casual speech it doesn't matter right? using だ for a question is acceptable only on conversations or in a more casual writing too?

Comment: Actually, in *formal* but *not polite* writing (e.g. essay, novel, academic paper), you'd see 「何/どう/どこ etc + の**か** ？/のだろう**か** ？/のであろう**か** ？etc」 rather than 「何/どう/どこ etc + だ？」. I'm not sure if this applies to all cases but I have a feeling that 「何/どう/どこ etc + の？/ のだ？」 is pretty conversational (You'd use it in casual emails/letters too, of course).

Answer (score 1):

According to the "Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar" page 322:
"の is sentence-final particle used by a female speaker or a child to indicate an explanation or emotive emphasis."

So the の used at the end of the sentence is used for emphasis.

Comment: And does the book say it also applies to interrogative sentences?

Comment: yes i have this doubt too, because i'm aware that affirmative sentences ending with の instead of のだ or のです are feminine/childish, but does it applies to interrogative ones? I hear things like [どうしたの？] mainly from girls in anime (but of course i know anime speech is not always what japanese people use daily)

Comment: Yes, it applies to interrrogative sentences.
It even has the sentence どうしたの? as an example.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask whether the statement "the の used at the end of the sentence is used for emphasis" applies to interrogative sentences. And I doubt it does. I think the の at the end of interrogative sentences indicates explanation, not emphasis.

Answer (score 1):

The explanatory [の] particle　is usually use in casual speech to make actual question.

In casual speech, The question marker [か] is often used to consider whether something is true or not.

By using [のか], you would be requesting a yes-no-answer along with an explanatory answer afterward.

**[か] :**

**"Is there any problem ?**

**[の] :**

**"What is the problem ?"**

**[のか] :**

**"Is there any problem ? If yes, then what it is ?"**

Comment: oh, that's helpful! Any insight on the feminine/childish tone that ending an interrogative sentence with の only could bring? Thank you!

Comment: [の] does sound very soft and feminine, but I'm not sure whether [の] is more feminine than [のか].

Comment: Ending with のですか？ would make it more masculine in your opinion? But as a result it would become polite speech right?

Comment: This is a very good answer to your question about the difference between [か] and [のか]:
http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18613/what-is-the-meaning-of-%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8B-and-how-does-it-differ-from-%E3%81%8B