# What does "なのか" mean in 彼女 が 誰 なのか わかりますか?

Tags: translation, particles, sentence-final-particles

彼女 が 誰 なのか わかりますか。is a question which has 2 "ka" question markers? or is it 2 questions? (Could it be translated as who is she? you know? ) 
And what does the "なの" means here? I think I've heard other phrases with "なのか" and I dont know when it has to be used

Comment: First か is for the embedded question, second for the main clause. 'who she is'; 'do you know'. Do you know who she is? なの makes something explanatory and follows a noun - here for an embedded question. I think 彼女 がだれか by itself might sound unnatural? I'm putting this here as a comment because I do not have enough authority to give a definite explanation of なの.

Comment: I dont really understand what it means when people says "it makes something explanatory".

Comment: @Pablo, the translation is "Do you know who she is?". I found a similar post with more detailed explanation, may be you will understand better after reading. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18613/what-is-the-meaning-of-%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8B-and-how-does-it-differ-from-%E3%81%8B

Comment: According to http://www.imabi.net/, the のか adds more uncertainty or seriousness to the question. As English has no similar distinction for embedded questions, it is somewhat more difficult to understand from the point of view of an English speaker.

Comment: @maki but what about the "な" . What is it for?

Comment: It's not different either with or without なの.

Comment: @user4092 it's cool to know that but I guess the な it gives some nuance to the sentence?

Comment: @Pablo The な doesn't add any nuance. It's just だ (to be). But だ always changes to な when の comes after.