# Is it rude to ask a question that ends with だ?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I'm going over the entry for のだ in my grammar dictionary, and I pretty much understand the meaning, but I'm unsure about casual question forms:

- んだ   (male) / の (female)　　　 んだい? (male) / の? (female)

Two examples:

> 「今行くの？」(f)
>
> 「今行くんだい?」(m)

The female form I am okay with. But I have never heard だい before, and I remember being told that it's very uncommon. I think males might simply say

> 「今行くんだ？」

Am I correct? But I've read that this can sound too interrogative or accusatory if the intonation is not right, so how would I say it properly?

Finally, I've seen のか, what is the difference? Is it feminine?

Comment: What is so feminine about 「の」?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. This is what is said in my grammar dictionary.

Comment: @nehry The grammar book likely said that _explanatory_ の sounds feminine, while _questioning_ の is gender-neutral.

Comment: @kroki so I can't say 「今行くんだ？」but 「今行くの？」is ok? The grammar book did say that both explanatory　の and question の is feminine, but in another entry it said that question の is used by both females and males.

Comment: @nehry My guess is that you are reading Tae Kim's guide.  This is a great book, but you should read it _very carefully_.  For instance it also explained that you use かい for yes/no questions, and だい when you expect some explanation, as Choco-san pointed you.

Answer (score 6):

"今行くんだい?" looks highly unnatural to me regardless of gender/situation. Sentence-end だい in questions appear *mainly by males in fiction* and *always with an interrogative*, e.g., "何故だい?" or "誰だい?" (This い is a [sentence-end particle](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/9100/meaning/m0u/). You can say "行くか?", "行くのか?" and "誰だ?" but usually not "行くだ?" or "誰か?" in conversation, right?)

"今行くんだ?" is a natural and casual way of expressing surprise and saying "(Oh,) you're going now?" It's not particularly masculine in real-world conversation.

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessarily rude to ask a question that ends in んだ or のだ (Both are the same, by the way). And, neither are gendered. The reason ん/のだ can sound interrogative is because it carries an air of presumption about what you're asking.

> 今行くの？ = Are you going now?

> 今行くんだ？ = So, you're going now?

Both are functionally the same, but the former is asking, up front, if the other person is going or not, while the second already *assumes* the person *is* leaving, and is merely checking.

As for のか, it is not gendered, either. In fact, のか can be pretty different from just か/ですか/の. I would read [this thread](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18613/what-is-the-meaning-of-%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8B-and-how-does-it-differ-from-%E3%81%8B) here on it. But, assuming it is being used in a non wh-question, *and* does not appear in the middle of sentence (aka it is being used as a sentence-ending particle), the best way to describe it, I think, is to think of it as expressing doubt, while ですか or の are more neutral.

> 本当に面白いの？ = is [it] actually funny? (neutral)

> 本当に面白いのか? = is [it] actually *that* funny? (doubting)

Answer (score 1):

From [Tae Kim's grammar guide](http://guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/sentence_ending):

> かい and だい are strongly masculine sentence endings for asking questions. かい is used for yes/no questions while だい is used for open-ended questions.

I believe that guide covers everything you mentioned in your question.