# Is it かも？ Or some particles? I'm lost with this sentence!

Tags: particle-の, particle-も, sentence-final-particles, particle-か, sentence

In 時をかける少女, the mother ask her daughter to bring something to her aunt, and then add this:

> いつになったら結婚するのかも聞いといてね

Which I understand as : "Ask her also when is she gonna marry someone!"

(When-become-when²-marriage-do- and then i'm lost with のかも like, is it の"emphasis ​female term or language" + "か question mark particle" and then "も also" ? or the word "かも" as "may; might; perhaps; may be; possibly​" ?)

Oh and why is 聞いて　with a と here? "Go ask" ? "聞いといて ! " ?

I haven't learned this yet, so sorry.. or can you guys link me a page where i can learn this?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Why would it be かも as in かもしれない?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

parse it like this:

> 「いつになったら結婚するのか」**も** 聞いといてね
>
> Oh, and **also** ask (her) when is she planning to get married.

**Edit**: for `のか` used as ending of question sentences, check [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18994/3295)

P.S. `聞いといて` is colloquial for `聞いておいて`. I think we have other questions on the `〜ておく` form but I don’t have a link handy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll check it!
I would have never guessed that, about 聞いといて..